# Constructing a Random Variable from Pre-set Moments

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose I wanted to construct a random variable $X$ so that $E(X)=p$ and $E(X^2)=2p^2$, for $0<p<1$. Suppose there are no constraints on the other moments. Is $X$ well-defined (Edit: “well-defined” in the sense that no contradiction arises from defining a random variable with the given moments)

And more generally, are there any theorems that outline constraints for constructing well-defined random variables from moments in this sort of way?

Comment: There are many random variables $X$ such that $E(X)=p$ and $E(X^2)=p^2$.  Just specifying two moments does not determine their distribution uniquely, so "well defined" fails.  There is a thing called "moment sequence" that you should learn about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two moments don't determine a distribution uniquely. For example, consider a normal distribution with mean $p$ and variance $p^2$. This has the same first two moments as an exponential distribution with rate $1/p$, which also has mean $p$ and variance $p^2$.

The question of whether a list of moments determines a unique distribution is known as the [Moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem). Without additional constraints, to determine the distribution uniquely you need the moments of every order, and often that's not even enough. For details see the related question [Constructing a probability function from its moments.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698999/constructing-a-probability-function-from-its-moments?rq=1), and also [this Math Overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/3525).

As for whether your two constraints produce a well-defined random variable, yes, there exist distributions satisfying $E(X)=p$ and $E(X^2)=2p^2$, as shown by the above two examples. In general you can construct random variables satisfying a finite list of conditions as long as the equations that are implied by that list are solvable. For example, if you imagine a *discrete* random variable that takes values $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ with probabilities $p_1,\ldots,p_n$, then the constraint $E(X)=p$ is the same as the equation
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_ip_i = p$$
and the constraint $E(X^2)=2p^2$ is the same as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2p_i=2p^2.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don’t mean if the chosen moments uniquely determine the random variable, but if one can choose values for some combination of moments and expect the existence of some valid random variable with the chosen moments

Comment: @gfppoy In general, you can -- see my edit.

Comment: That’s cool thanks!